# Uploading multi sql with sessions cart

Tags: php, mysql

How do I upload multi product name with single table?
(Here is my current sql update it working on single not multi):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO order_details(product_name) VALUES('$product_name')";
```

And this is my example input form cart using sessions (already cut some line coz it too long):

```html
       <?php
     if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) //check session var
        {
      $total = 0; //set initial total value
      $b = 0; //var for zebra stripe table 
      foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
            {
       //set variables to use in content below
       $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
       $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
       $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
       $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
       $product_color = $cart_itm["product_color"];
       $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty); //calculate Price x Qty
       
          $bg_color = ($b++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even'; //class for zebra stripe 
    echo '<td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" class="inp_check " name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" />
      </section>
    </td>';
    echo '<td width="40%" align="left"><input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="'.$product_name.'">'.$product_name.'</td>';
    echo '<td width="5%" align="center"><input type="number" size="2" class="ip_remove" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /> Unit</td>'
```

What I want to do is when people click button submit it should upload sql like with a single update

```
    id    order_id    product_name     product_price
    1     14           iphone 7        USD700  
    1     14           iphone 7s       USD700     
    1     14           iphone 5        USD700

    2     15           iphone 7       USD700
    2     15           iphone 7s      USD700
    2     15           iphone 5      USD700
```

or this example photo
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`values` in sql can accept multiple entries, example:

```
INSERT INTO order_details(product_name) 
VALUES
    ('product1'),
    ('producut2'),
    ('product3');
```